# Is there a way to control on Report of Surefire plugin?

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, maven-3, pom.xml

Is it possible to have control on listed folders for Maven Project(target folder), If we don't want to generate it ?

[image: Maven-Target Folder]

One of it called "surefire-reports" is from "maven-surefire-plugin", Can we have configuration to control it ? If we don't want to generate those.

**POM.XML :**

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                     <suiteXmlFiles> 
                         <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile> 
                     </suiteXmlFiles>                       
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

**skipSurefireReport:**

If set to true the surefire report generation will be skipped.

1. Type: boolean
2. Required: No
3. User Property:skipSurefireReport
4. Default: false

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-mojo.html#skipSurefireReport.

**skipSurefireTests:**

Goal:

```
mvn clean verify -DskipTests=true
```

try with this code with goal as mentioned above

```
 <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                   <skip.surefire.tests>${skipTests}</skip.surefire.tests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

this code will skip the surefire tests.

[Skip report generation using TestNG and sure-fire plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738103/skip-report-generation-using-testng-and-sure-fire-plugin)

[Prevent unit tests in maven but allow integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612344/prevent-unit-tests-in-maven-but-allow-integration-tests)

Comment: Still it is generating. I need to generate tickets for same. As according to Maven description it should not has to generate it.

Comment: Its Not Working.

Comment: Its regarding report issue to Apache.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on version of the plugin.

My comments here are for [last version 3.2.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/3.2.5):

[Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) is IMO not clear, here is how I finally stopped generating of both xml and txt reports:

```
-DdisableXmlReport=true -Dsurefire.useFile=false
```

(or you can put these parameters into properties in your pom.xml)